# find available rooms querying to bookings with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections, and i want to find available rooms between two dates `2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z` and `2021-10-31T23:59:59.999Z`

### bookings

`{from:Date, to:Date, room:ObjectId, status:Boolean}`

### rooms

`{_id:ObjectId, code:String, status:Boolean}`

Any idea?

Comment: you can compare the date with `$lte`, `$gte` in a `$match` stage and use `$lookup` to get the room information, see mongodb documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aggregate

```
db.bookings.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "from": {
            "$lt": "2021-10-16T23:59:59.999Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "to": {
            "$gt": "2021-10-13T23:59:59.999Z"
          }
        }
      ],
      "status": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "1",
      "notAvailableRooms": {
        $addToSet: "$room"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "rooms",
      let: {
        ids: "$notAvailableRooms"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $not: {
                    $in: [
                      "$_id",
                      "$$ids"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$status",
                    true
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "availableRooms"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "availableRooms": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pJCM0mmG8vy)